# Converting xarray to numpy.array is very very slow

Tags: python, python-xarray

I have **1D** **xarray** called `A` with a shape of `(120,)`. I am trying to convert xarray `A` to **numpy array** using the following line:

`A = np.array(A)`

However, the process takes **01m:26sec** to be done, although the array isn't that big.

I am reading such xarray from combined netCDF files using the following command:

`data = xr.open_mfdataset('/path/*.nc',concat_dim='time_counter', combine='nested')`

`A = data.A`

So, how can I speed up converting the xarray to np.array ?!

Comment: Maybe https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.as_numpy.html ?

Comment: Note also that when you open your dataset with `open_mfdataset` it returns a dask array dataset, so you haven’t actually loaded the data yet until you convert to numpy. Try `ds = ds.load()` first to separate the load/compute time from the time to convert to numpy.

Comment: It works, however it takes too much time to load the dataset (ds).

Comment: how many files are you reading? is this 120 files with 1 data point in each? I could see that taking this long... or is `/path` networked over a slow connection? this is now a "why is it taking so long to read data with `xr.open_mfdataset`" question, not anything to do with conversion to numpy.